# How can I record from my Nikon Coolpix S8200 direct to photobooth?

Tags: camera, photo-booth

I went to the Nikon site and installed S-VCNXSP-160500MF-ALLIN-ALL, but those are just transfer and editing stuff, I want to record from photobooth the raw live video.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably going to need [Camera Control Pro 2](http://www.europe-nikon.com/en_GB/product/software/camera-control-pro-2) - the only one of their suite that isn't free. Though if you buy it from a retailer, not direct from Nikon, it's about ⅓ the price.

I have a Nikon D5500 & also a Logitech HD Pro C920 webcam - neither of which are natively supported by QuickTime.
Using an app called [Webcam Settings](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webcam-settings/id533696630?mt=12) it can persuade the Logitech to show as a source for QuickTime/Photo Booth etc - but it can't persuade the Nikon to show at all.

It's perfectly happy recording from Camera Control, though, including Live View to the Mac & also file transfer.